# Cauchy products for 4 power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

$A= a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+...$

$B= b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3+b_4x^4+...$

$A\cdot B=a_0b_0+(a_0b_1+a_1b_0)x+(a_0b_2+a_1b_1+a_2b_0)x^2...$

So I can build a triangle by detailing the coefficients of the two above series:

$a_0b_0$

$a_0b_1+a_1b_0$

$a_0b_2+a_1b_1+a_2b_0$

$a_0b_3+a_1b_2+a_2b_1+a_3b_0$

I can keep writing, notice that the subscript for $a$ doesn't change. It is easy to write these coefficients in a triangle which I call the Cauchy triangle.

Recently, however, I encounter a problem that asks me to deal with the product of four power series instead of two. So I wish to build up a triangle that is similar to the case of two power series.

I write the four power series as followed:

$A= a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+...$

$B= b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3+b_4x^4+...$

$C= c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+c_4x^4+...$

$D= d_0+d_1x+d_2x^2+d_3x^3+d_4x^4+...$

$A\cdot B\cdot C\cdot D=a_0b_0c_0d_0+(a_1b_0c_0d_0+a_0b_1c_0d_0+a_0b_0c_1d_0)x+(a_0b_2c_0d_0+a_2b_0c_0d_0+a_0b_0c_2d_0+a_0b_0c_0d_2                            
                                 )x^2...$

This is the best I can try so far, is there a method to exhaustively list all these elements into a triangle like the case of two power series? I want a complete triangle to fully count the coefficients.

Please don't respond to this thread with full sigma notation, as I haven't mastered the procedure of manipulating these symbols yet.

Comment: For the $x^2$ term you've missed $6$ cases: $a_0b_0c_1d_1$ and so forth.  For the $x$ term you missed $a_0b_0c_0d_1$

Comment: @saulspatz, this is why I wish to make a triangle so that I don't miss counting any term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you multiply two power series, the general term is $$(a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+\cdots+a_nb_0)x^n.$$  The subscripts sums to $n$.  Note that there are always $n+1$ terms in the coefficient, since the subscript on $a$ must be $0\leq k\leq n$ and then there is only once choice for the subscript on $b$.  The number of terms grows linearly with $n$, so they fit neatly in a triangle.

When you multiply $4$ power series a typical term in the coefficient of $x^n$ looks like $a_ib_jc_kd_l$ where $i+j+k+l=n$.  There are $$\binom{n+3}{3}=\frac{(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)}{6}$$ such terms.  (Google "stars and bars" if you don't know how I arrived at this expression.)  Therefore, they won't fit it a triangle.

Obviously, knowing how many terms there should be will help you not miss any.  What I would suggest is that in passing from $x^n$ to $x^{n+1}$ you add $1$ to each of the subscripts in the each term in the coefficient for $x^n$, taking care to avoid duplicates.  For example, the coefficient of $x$ has $4$ and the coefficient for $x^2$ has $10$.  If we add $1$ to each subscript in each term, we get $4$ times as many terms.  This would give $16$ terms in the coefficient of $x^2$, not $10$.  The reason is that there is more than one way to arrive at certain terms.  For example $a_1b_1c_0d_0$ could arise from adding $1$ to the subscript of $a$ in $a_0b_1c_0d_0$ or from adding $1$ to the subscript of $b$ in $a_1b_0c_0d_0$.

That said, you will see that the numbers of terms quickly becomes too large to make listing them explicitly worthwhile.  You really should learn how to use the sigma notation.

Comment: Thank you saulspatz!

Comment: @JamesWarthington It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient of $x^n$
is the sum of all
$a_ib_jc_kd_l$
with
$i+j+k+l = n$.

You can see this
by noting that
the terms with
such
$a_ib_jc_kd_l$
is
$a_ix^ib_jx^jc_kx^kd_lx^l$
$=a_ib_jc_kd_lx^{i+j+k+l}$.